# Overly eager regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to avoid emails in my input field boxes, so I'm using multiple regex for this, I got one that is matching more than I want, this is the regex :

```
(at( )*\w+(\b\.ie\b|\b\ .ie\b))
```

And its supposed to match attempts like email at domain.ie but I got also this part matching :

also wh`at a tie` they are

How can I modify this regex not to match this case?

I tried this :

```
(at( )[a-z^\s]\w+(\b\.ie\b|\b\ .ie\b))
```

and couple of more things, still I get the same match, how can I still keep the matching that I want but to avoid this case

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to match something like "at foo.ie" or "at foo .ie"?  I think something as simple as this will work based on your question: `/\bat +\w+ ?\.ie\b/`

Comment: can you please make this an answer this is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match something like "at foo.ie" or "at foo .ie", something as simple as this will work: `/\bat +\w+ ?\.ie\b/`

Comment: Doesn't match `at foo .ie`

Comment: irb disagrees: `/\bat +\w+ ?\.ie\b/.match 'at foo .ie'` `=> #<MatchData "at foo .ie">`

Comment: Well, if this SO editor wasn't so messed up, you would have seen it as "at\tfoo\t.ie" like I posted that won't match your regex.

Comment: Aha, I see. :)  Judging by Gandalf's attempt in his original question, he explicitly wants space characters... but if you want any whitespace, it's easy to match that instead: `/\bat\s+\w+\s?\.ie\b/`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the unexpected match, try using a literal period `\.` in your regular expression.  Testing that against a few inputs looks like it gets what you want:

```
tests = [
  {:text => 'at domain.ie',             :expected => true},
  {:text => 'at something.ie',          :expected => true},
  {:text => 'at foo.ie',                :expected => true},
  {:text => 'also what a tie they are', :expected => false}
]

regex = /\bat\s+\w+\s?\.ie\b/

tests.each do |test|
  text         = test[:text]
  expect_match = test[:expected]
  matched = false
  if text =~ regex
    matched = true
  end

  if expect_match == matched
    puts "OK:     expected=#{expect_match} == #{matched} for regex=#{regex} vs text=#{text}"
  else
    puts "NOT OK: expected=#{expect_match} != #{matched} for regex=#{regex} vs text=#{text}"
  end
end
```

If you have more test cases, it should be easy to add them to the above code - though you may wish to make a more formal test using something like [rspec](http://rspec.info/).